# Power BI Query Editor - Inserting Rows to the Bottom of a Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table that looks like this in Power BI:

```
CourseID      Course
1             Math
2             Cooking
3             English
4             Spanish
```

I want to insert a row at the bottom that looks like this:

```
-1            null
```

I looked at the Microsoft Documentation, but it's not very helpful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong.

Let's say I wanted to insert a row, at top of a table, named `Courses`.

The M query would look like this

```
#Insert Row = Table.InsertRows(#PreviousStepName,0,{[CourseID=-1,Course=null]})
```

Was not able to get it working if the column name had a space in it, but for best practices, you shouldn't have columns with spaces in the name anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to insert a row to the bottom of a table:

**Step 1:** Go to the edit query window. select the correct table.

**Step 2:** Go to the APPLIED STEPS window on the right-hand side. double click on Source.

**Step 3:** Add the data to each column and press ok.

Note that, this will only add a row to the end of the table.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you are using a source other than manual. In my case this is data from a database, and if I double-click on Source I get a window for which database to use.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer above by OP works great if you want to insert a row at the top of the table, or if you know the index to insert at. In my case I want to append to the end, and the amount of rows is likely to change in future.

I saw the functions to reverse the rows, so you could reverse the rows, insert at 0, then reverse again, but I found another way:

```ml
#"Insert Row" = Table.Combine({#"Previous Step Name",
    Table.FromRows(
        {{null, "None", true, false}},
        {"ID", "Name", "Deleted", "IsIntegration"}
    )
})
```

Basically, you create a new table with Table.FromRows, then use Table.Combine to append it

Comment: With Combine, you lose table type, including keys
So, I suspect that the performance of Combine should be better. But how much better? Or not?

Comment: @BasilPeace A good question, in my case the existing data only had around 20 rows so I wouldn't be able to notice any difference.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically add row(s) to the bottom then use `Table.RowCount` like so...

```
#Insert Row = Table.InsertRows(#PreviousStepName, Table.RowCount(#PreviousStepName), {[CourseID=-1, Course=null]})
```